# Optimal Design of a Ruby Data Structures Library

Tags: ruby, oop, data-structures

I am working with data structures fundamentals in Ruby for learning at the CS sophomore/junior level.

My question: Given the following code, does anyone see any design issues with this approach to a data structures library in Ruby?  Especially the Module#abstract_method. Is it okay to do this in terms of duck typing philosophy?  Does this make the code clearer for people from static languages and give some semblance of an interface?

```
class Module

  def abstract_method(symbol)
    module_eval <<-"end_eval"
      def #{symbol.id2name}(*args)
        raise MethodNotImplementedError
      end
    end_eval
  end

end

class AbstractObject < Object

  abstract_method :compare_to
  protected :compare_to

  class MethodNotImplementedError < StandardError; end

  def initialize
    super
  end

  include Comparable

  def <=>(other)
    if is_a?(other.class)
      return compare_to(other)
    elsif other.is_a?(self.class)
      return -other.compare_to(self)
    else
      return self.class <=> other.class
    end
  end

end

# methods for insertion/deletion should be provided by concrete implementations as this behavior
# is unique to the type of data structure. Also, concrete classes should override purge to discard
# all the contents of the container

class Container < AbstractObject

  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    super
    @count = 0
  end

  attr_reader :count
  alias :size :count

  # should return an iterator
  abstract_method :iter

  # depends on iterator object returned from iter method
  # layer of abstraction for how to iterate a structure
  def each
    i = iter
    while i.more?
      yield i.succ
    end
  end

  # a visitor provides another layer of abstraction for additional
  # extensible and re-usable traversal operations
  def accept(visitor)
    raise ArgumentError, "Argument must be a visitor" unless visitor.is_a?(Visitor)
    each do |obj|
      break if visitor.done?
      visitor.visit(obj)
    end
  end

  # expected to over-ride this in derived classes to clear container
  def purge
    @count = 0
  end

  def empty?
    count == 0
  end

  def full?
    false
  end

  def to_s
    s = ""
    each do |obj|
      s << ", " if not s.empty?
      s << obj.to_s
    end
    self.class + "{" + s + "}"
  end


end

class List < Container

  def initialize
    super
  end

  def compare_to(obj)
   "fix me"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

A few remarks:

- Defining a method that only raises a NotImplemented error is somewhat redundant, since Ruby will do that anyway if the method does not exist. The code you wrote there is just as useful as simply putting a comment to say "You must implement a method called compare_to". In fact that is what the Enumerable module in Ruby's standard library does - in the documentation it specifically says that in order to use the functionality in Enumerable you must define an each() method.
- a compare_to method is also redundant, since that is precisely what the <=> operator is for.
- Using an actual iterator object is a bit overkill in Ruby, since blocks tend to have a much more elegant and simple approach. Same goes for your visitor pattern - you don't need to use a visitor for "extensible and re-usable traversal operations" when you can just pass a block to a traverse method. For example you have many of them in Enumerable: each, each_with_index, map, inject, select, delete_if, partition, etc. All of these use a block in a different way to provide a different type of functionality, and other functionality can be added on in a fairly simple and consistent way (especially when you have open classes).
- Regarding interfaces, in Ruby (and pretty much any other dynamic language, like Python) people usually use interfaces that are *implicit*, which means that you don't actually define the interface in code. Instead you typically rely on documentation and proper testing suites to ensure that code works well together.

I think that your code may be more coherent to someone coming from a Java world because it sticks to the "Java way" of doing things. However to other Ruby programmers your code would be confusing and difficult to work with since it doesn't really stick to the "Ruby way" of doing things. For example, an implementation of a select function using an iterator object:

```
it = my_list.iter
results = []

while it.has_next?
  obj = it.next

  results << obj if some_condition?
end
```

is much less clear to a Ruby programmer than:

```
results = my_list.select do |obj|
  some_condition?
end
```

If you would like to see an example of a data structures library in Ruby, you can see the algorithms gem here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/algorithms/0.3.0/frames

Also take a look at what is provided by default in the Enumerable module: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html. When you include Enumerable you receive all of these functions for free.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I would go even further: the code in the question is not just "confusing and difficult to work with" for a Ruby programmer, it simply isn't Ruby. Period. It's Java with Ruby syntax. Well, actually, since it isn't really object-oriented either, it's more like Pascal with Ruby syntax.

Comment: So there isn't any advantage to having the enumeration strategies as classes which can be abstract and thus arbitrarily replaced with concrete implementations? It seems that a block is only an anonymous method for quick one-off jobs and wouldn't be reusable or easily replaceable with other algorithms, etc..

Comment: It is easily replaceable, when you call the enumeration method you can simply pass a different block to a method when you need a different algorithm ;) Furthermore, a block can be made reusable by converting it to a Proc or lambda and then can be passed to other methods, stored in variables, etc. Enumeration strategies using objects is also possible in Ruby 1.9 with Enumerator objects, but using the Java method of Iterators requires a lot of extra "boiler-plate" for 90% of the use cases of enumeration: something that Rubyists consider bad design.

Comment: thanks, helps. I had a feeling this language was more powerful than I suspected.

Comment: Upon reading this again, I am thinking the fact that the each method is the one using the iterator makes this a more powerful pattern that first appears.  I don't think you would say it = my_list.iter, you would say my_list.each which uses an iterator internally based on the concrete iter implementation. So my_list.each {|x| do_stuff } varies based on the strategy implemented for the particular list.

Comment: Exactly! That way for a tree you can implement an each method differently than a queue, etc.